# What is the difference between guestOS from VM and Base Image from Docker?

Tags: linux, docker, linux-kernel, operating-system, virtual-machine

## As I know

Docker makes containers share Linux kernel. Using namespace and Cgroup, Container can be independent from other containers. And Sharing Linux kernel, Container doesn't need GuestOS occupying big space from hardware any more so We can save a lot of resource by using Docker. But I came to know that each Docker image has base image and base image is mostly OS. For example, If I do  `docker run redis:alpine`, alpine the linux os would be base Image.

## My question is

Then what is the difference between having base image and having guestOS? In the case above I wrote, Is alpine GuestOs?